# MAMP Localhost not working (Error 500) - LWT

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I am trying to run [LWT](http://lwt.sourceforge.net/#installmac) on my mac and have installed MAMP for this. I have followed [these instructions](http://lwt.sourceforge.net/#installmac), but when I try to go to `http://localhost:8888/lwt/` I am getting:

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> 500

I have created a different folder in my htdocs folder and created a php file in it (index.php), with some code to see if php is working:

```
<?php
echo "this is the start";
phpinfo();
echo "<br>this is the end";
?>
```

That is all fine and works. I have also checked the user-rights for the lwt folder, but it seems fine too (Admins & Me are Read&Write, Others are ReadOnly). Typing `tail -f /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log` into the terminal gives me the following error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lwt/utilities.inc.php:3272
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lwt/index.php(46): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lwt/utilities.inc.php on line 3272
```

I am a beginner though, so I don't know what else the problem could be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which version of PHP you use. But the `mysql_*` function are deprecated and its possible that its not included in your new version anymore. Use `mysqli_*` to connect to your database or use PDO.

In the new version of MAMP is PHP7 included. Perhaps you use that.

Comment: I have just solved my problem by using an older version of PHP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You shouldn't use the deprecated functions ;) that it a much better way.

Comment: thanks! but I do not know how configure it so that it'll use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.